# comparing two groups inside a column in r

Tags: r

I generated subgroups in a column, I want to compare between Group4 and Group9 using t.test, this is the head of my dataset:

```
         gene_id         expr   Var     Group   grp
           <chr>       <int>  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>
1   ENSG00000000003     1138    0      Other    xxxxx3XX
2   ENSG00000000005        6    0      Other    xxxxx5XX
3   ENSG00000000419      754    4      Group4   xxxxx4XX
4   ENSG00000000457     447     4      Group4   xxxxx4XX
5   ENSG00000000460      426    4      Group4   xxxxx4XX
6   ENSG00000000938        5    9      Group9   xxxxx9XX
```

I tried:

```
t.test(df1$Group4, df1$Group9)
```

I get this error:

```
Warning message in mean.default(x):
“argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA”
Error in var(x): 'x' is NULL
Traceback:

1. t.test(df1$Group4, df1$Group9)
2. t.test.default(df1$Group4, df1$Group9)
3. var(x)
```

I couldn't get the dput of the data because it is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset those specific groups, select relevant column and then peform `t.test` on it.

```
t.test(subset(df, Group == 'Group4')$expr, subset(df, Group == 'Group9')$expr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RonakShah, can I adjusted the code to one tail or two tail? How to run the heatmap for the same groups?

Comment: I think by default `t.test` performs two tail test. For one test you can use `alternative` argument in it.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, can I generate heatmap for the same groups?